# some important proofs about adjoint operators

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

I was told that the formal adjoint of the gradient is the negative divergence.

Let $A : H\to H$ be a bounded, linear operator, The adjoint of $A$, i.e. $A^*: H\to H$ satisfies
\begin{equation*}
 (Au,v)=(u,A^*v)
\end{equation*}
for all $u, v\in H$.
Moreover, $A$ is symmetric if $A^*=A$.

Could anyone help me to verify the claim:

what would be the adjoint of the gradient in the space $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$?

Comment: Do you mean $L^2(\Bbb R^n)$?

Comment: I think there should be answers in both both $L^(\mathbb{R})$ and $L^(\mathbb{R}^n)$ cases.

Comment: This is a new question to the other 3.